# iOS push notification using FCM

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently we are using AWS for sending IOS push notifications and FCM for Android notifications. As FCM also supports IOS notifications, we want to consider that for 2 reasons

1. It is free service (AWS is not that costly)
2. to have single interface from app server for push and web notifications

but from FCM documentation, it looks IOS app has to be tightly integrated with FCM API for delivering push notifications (this is not required for AWS). so i want to know if there is a way I can send push notifications without any change to iOS app code.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS app **must** be configured to receive messages from the FCM Servers.

You'll have to implement the necessary functions (callbacks specifically) in your client app that will handle/receive the messages as mentioned in the [Setting Up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client).

It's also through implementing the needed functions you'll be able to generate a token needed by the FCM servers to send a message towards the device(s).

Comment: is setting up required even if I want to use APN?

Comment: If you intend to use FCM with APNs, then yes.